# Testing repository method

Tags: tdd, mstest

As the title suggests I'm trying to test a method, unfortunately I appear to be going wrong some where. The method should only return customers that have and ID = 1

Here is my test

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void Returns_Correct_Number_Of_Workout_Dates_For_Valid_UserId()
        {

        //Arrange
        List<GymSession> gymSessions = new List<GymSession>();

        Customer cust = new Customer();

        cust.CustomerId = 1;

        gymSessions.Add(new GymSession() { Customer = cust, SessionId = 1, Date = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1)  });
        gymSessions.Add(new GymSession() { Customer = cust, SessionId = 2, Date = new DateTime(2010, 1, 2) });
        gymSessions.Add(new GymSession() { SessionId = 3, Date = new DateTime(2010, 1, 3) });
        gymSessions.Add(new GymSession() { Customer = cust, SessionId = 4, Date = new DateTime(2010, 1, 4) });

        var mockRepos = new Moq.Mock<IGymSessionRepository>();
        mockRepos.Setup(g => g.GymSession()).Returns(gymSessions.AsQueryable());

        //Act
        var result = mockRepos.Object.GetWorkoutDatesByCustomerId(1);

        //Assert
         Assert.AreEqual(3, result.Count());
        }
```

Here is the repository method I'm trying to test

```
        public IQueryable<GymSession> GetWorkoutDatesByCustomerId(int userId)
    {
        var gymSess = db.GymSessions.Where<GymSession>(g => g.Customer.CustomerId == userId);

        return gymSess;
    }
```

The idea is that setup has all the customers, and the method then filters them. The count never seems to apply the filter. Any ideas?

Comment: Does `GymSession` have a default customer? If `GymSession.Customer` is null, won't the predicate throw?

Comment: It doesn't have a default customer. The result is always 4. I'm new to testing so I suspect I'm either getting the setup wrong, or assigning the result variable incorrectly. But tbh I've no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you really want to stub the call to `db.GymSessions` and that you should test a concrete `GymSessionRepository` instance. Traditionally, there are two ways to do this (apart from intercepting calls using aspect-oriented programming):

1) Give your repository an explicit dependency on `db` and require it in the repository constructor. Here's what I mean, where I'm using `IDatabase` to represent `db`:

```
public class GymSessionRepository: IGymSessionRepository {
    private IDatabase db;
    public GymSessionRepository(IDatabase db) {
        this.db = db;
    }
}

// Then in your test ...
var mockDb = new Moq.Mock<IDatabase>();
mockDb.Setup(d => d.GymSessions()).Returns(gymSessions.AsQueryable());

GymSessionRepository repository = new GymSessionRepository(mockDb);
// ... and so on
```

2) (Less desirable, but sometimes necessary) Expose the method you want to stub as a virtual member, mock the concrete object you're testing, and stub the behavior directly on the class under test:

```
public class GymSessionRepository {
    // Because this is virtual, you can override it in your mock object
    protected virtual List<GymSession> GymSessions() {
        return this.db.GymSessions.AsQueryable();
    }
}

// In your test code here: notice the mock object is your concrete class,
// because your test targets another method on that class, not a method 
// on an arbitrary implementation (like a mock based on its interface)
var mockRepos = new Moq.Mock<GymSessionRepository>();

// Override its virtual method; take control for your test
mockRepos.Setup(g => g.GymSessions()).Returns(gymSessions.AsQueryable());
```

Depending on the mocking framework, the second technique is known as using a [transparent](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/nmock2/index.php?title=MockStyle) or [partial](http://www.ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Partial+Mocks.ashx) mock. If you find yourself using it often, it may be a sign that your code is overly-coupled (and it can get confusing fast).

Comment: I had a sneaking suspician it was a long solution 1 lines. Many thanks.